# Get data from Dialog and post it to MainActivity

Tags: java, android

I am new to android. I have created a `Dialog` and in this `Dialog` I have 2 `EditText` fields.

I want get the values(user entered) from this 2 `EditText` fields and show it to the 2 separate `TextView` fields in `MainActivity`But no matter how much I try, I can't get the value from `EditText` fields.

Please help. The code I have till now...

```
package edu.arnab.simpledialogmenu;

import android.app.AlertDialog;
import android.content.DialogInterface;
import android.content.DialogInterface.OnClickListener;
import android.graphics.Color;
import android.os.Bundle;
import android.support.v7.app.ActionBarActivity;
import android.view.Menu;
import android.view.MenuItem;
import android.view.View;
import android.widget.EditText;
import android.widget.RelativeLayout;
import android.widget.TextView;
import android.widget.Toast;


public class MainActivity extends ActionBarActivity implements OnClickListener {

    RelativeLayout layout;
    TextView tvTitle, tvCaption, tvStudio;
    EditText gTitle, gCaption;
    String title, caption;

    @Override
    protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
        setContentView(R.layout.activity_main);

        layout = (RelativeLayout) findViewById(R.id.relative1);

        tvTitle = (TextView) findViewById(R.id.textView1);
        tvCaption = (TextView) findViewById(R.id.textView2);
        tvStudio = (TextView) findViewById(R.id.textView3);

        registerForContextMenu(layout);
        registerForContextMenu(tvTitle);

    }

    @Override

    public void onCreateContextMenu(android.view.ContextMenu menu, android.view.View v, android.view.ContextMenu.ContextMenuInfo menuInfo) 
    {
        if(v == layout)
        {
            menu.add(1, 1, 0, "Make Background Yellow");
            menu.add(1, 2, 0, "Make Background Cyan");
        }
        else if(v == tvTitle)
        {

            menu.removeGroup(1);
            menu.add(2, 3, 0, "Make Title COD");
            menu.add(2, 4, 0, "Make Title NFS");
        }

        super.onCreateContextMenu(menu, v, menuInfo);
    };

    @Override
    public boolean onContextItemSelected(MenuItem item) {
        // TODO Auto-generated method stub

        switch(item.getItemId())
        {
            case 1:
                layout.setBackgroundColor(Color.YELLOW);
                break;
            case 2:
                layout.setBackgroundColor(Color.CYAN);
                break;
            case 3:
                tvTitle.setText("Title: Call of Duty");
                break;
            case 4:
                tvTitle.setText("Title: Need for Speed");
                break;
        }
        return super.onContextItemSelected(item);
    }

    public boolean onCreateOptionsMenu(Menu menu) {

        menu.add(1, 1, 1, "Game Entry Dialog");
        menu.add(1, 2, 1, "Change Background");
        menu.add(1, 3, 1, "Exit App");
        return true;
    }

    @Override
    public boolean onOptionsItemSelected(MenuItem item) {
        String text =  null;
        switch(item.getItemId())
        {
            case 1:
                text = item.getTitle().toString();
                // Show Game Dialog
                AlertDialog.Builder ab = new AlertDialog.Builder(this);
                ab.setTitle("New Game Entry Dialog");

                View view = getLayoutInflater().inflate(R.layout.dlg_layout, null);
                ab.setView(view);

                gTitle = (EditText) view.findViewById(R.id.editTitle);
                gCaption = (EditText) view.findViewById(R.id.editCaption);
                title = gTitle.getText().toString();
                caption = gCaption.getText().toString();



                ab.setPositiveButton("OKAY IT", this);
                ab.setNegativeButton("CANCEL IT", this);

                AlertDialog ad = ab.create();
                ad.show();

                break;
            case 2:
                text = item.getTitle().toString();

                layout.setBackgroundColor(Color.GREEN);
                tvTitle.setBackgroundColor(Color.WHITE);
                tvCaption.setBackgroundColor(Color.LTGRAY);
                break;
            case 3:
                text = item.getTitle().toString();

                finish();
                break;
        }

        Toast.makeText(this, "You have selected menu item " + text, 3000).show();
        return super.onOptionsItemSelected(item);
    }

    @Override
    public void onClick(DialogInterface arg0, int arg1) {
        // TODO Auto-generated method stub

        switch(arg1)
        {
            case DialogInterface.BUTTON_POSITIVE:
                //take text from dialog fields and show all info on MainActivity
                tvTitle.setText(title);
                tvCaption.setText(caption);
                break;
            case DialogInterface.BUTTON_NEGATIVE:
                Toast.makeText(this, "You cancelled dialog entry", 300).show();
                break;
        }

    }
}
```

Comment: Simply you can use interface and Event bus too

Comment: "I can't get the value from EditText fields."  Why? what is stopping you?

Comment: write this code `title = gTitle.getText().toString();
                caption = gCaption.getText().toString();` on `onClick` method of `BUTTON_POSITIVE`

Comment: @Kuffs With the code I have till now I am only getting blank value. There is now value in the variable name `title` or `caption`

Comment: @aksacha I did test your code. When I move the code inside `onclick` method of `BUTTON_POSITIVE` , I get error `view is not defined`.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Replcae your `onClick` method with this.

```
@Override
    public void onClick(DialogInterface arg0, int arg1) {
        // TODO Auto-generated method stub

        switch(arg1)
        {
            case DialogInterface.BUTTON_POSITIVE:
                //take text from dialog fields and show all info on MainActivity
                //these are changes
                title = gTitle.getText().toString(); 
                caption = gCaption.getText().toString();

                tvTitle.setText(title);
                tvCaption.setText(caption);
                break;
            case DialogInterface.BUTTON_NEGATIVE:
                Toast.makeText(this, "You cancelled dialog entry", 300).show();
                break;
        }

    }
```

Comment: if you find this answer helping so you can upvote it so other can get help from it.

Comment: I have upvoted your answer but I was shown this following notification : **Thanks for the feedback! Votes cast by those with less than 15 reputation are recorded, but do not change publicly displayed post score.** Sorry about that

Comment: No problem.. Happy Coding :)